# Angular $http.post to save data

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm using angular to in my application.  Finally got a handle on the get now trying to implement the post.  My issue is using the $http.post.

My error is ExceptionType: "System.ArgumentException"
Message: "Invalid JSON primitive: json." When I dont include the configuration object.

When I do include the config object then the error is "webmethod name is invalid"

Here is the code.

```
        vm.createCustomer = function () {
        var customerObject = {};
        customerObject.firstName = $("#firstName").val();
        customerObject.lastName = $("#lLastName").val();
        customerObject.company = $("#company").val();

        var data = $.param({
            json: JSON.stringify(customerObject)
        });

        $http.post("DAL/WebService.asmx/InsertCustomer", data).success(function(data, status){
            toastr.options = {
                "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
            }
            toastr.success("Created");
        })
    }
```

WebMethod

```
        [WebMethod]
    public void InsertCustomer(Customer c)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertCustomer", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "firstName",
                Value = c.firstName
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "lastName",
                Value = c.lastName
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "company",
                Value = c.company
            });

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `$http.post("DAL/WebService.asmx/InsertCustomer", customerObject)`?

Comment: then that creates missing parameter

Comment: What about `$http.post("DAL/WebService.asmx/InsertCustomer", $.param(customerObject))`?

Comment: closer now trying to figure out the Invalid JSON primitive: on my firstName

Comment: this doesn't look much like angular at all.  why are you using jquery to retrieve the value from your textboxes instead of using angular two way binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh only took 2.5 hours to figure out syntax

```
            $http.post("DAL/WebService.asmx/InsertCustomer", {c: customerObject}).then(function (customerObject, status) {
            toastr.options = {
                "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
            }
            toastr.success("Created");
        })
```